# Implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to create a channel from the CLI container,

I have set correct values for CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID = Org1MSP and CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH = /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.com/users/Admin@org1.com/msp .

But when trying to create the channel I am getting below error from orderer log

`identity 0 does not satisfy principal: This identity is not an admin`

and the response message is

`error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied`

Please find the configtx.yaml file below,

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

---
################################################################################
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
    - &OrdererOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

    - &Org1
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org1MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"

        # leave this flag set to true.
        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.org1.com
              Port: 7051

    - &Org2
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org2MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org2MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin')"

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.org2.com
              Port: 9051

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Capabilities
#
#   - This section defines the capabilities of fabric network. This is a new
#   concept as of v1.1.0 and should not be utilized in mixed networks with
#   v1.0.x peers and orderers.  Capabilities define features which must be
#   present in a fabric binary for that binary to safely participate in the
#   fabric network.  For instance, if a new MSP type is added, newer binaries
#   might recognize and validate the signatures from this type, while older
#   binaries without this support would be unable to validate those
#   transactions.  This could lead to different versions of the fabric binaries
#   having different world states.  Instead, defining a capability for a channel
#   informs those binaries without this capability that they must cease
#   processing transactions until they have been upgraded.  For v1.0.x if any
#   capabilities are defined (including a map with all capabilities turned off)
#   then the v1.0.x peer will deliberately crash.
#
################################################################################
Capabilities:
    # Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be
    # supported by both.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        # V1.3 for Channel is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all orderers and peers running at the v1.3.x
        # level, but which would be incompatible with orderers and peers from
        # prior releases.
        # Prior to enabling V1.3 channel capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers and peers on a channel are at v1.3.0 or later.
        V1_3: true

    # Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
    # used with prior release peers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        # V1.1 for Orderer is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all orderers running at the v1.1.x
        # level, but which would be incompatible with orderers from prior releases.
        # Prior to enabling V1.1 orderer capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers on a channel are at v1.1.0 or later.
        V1_1: true

    # Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
    # used with prior release orderers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        # V1.3 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.3.
        V1_3: true
        # V1.2 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.2 (note, this need not be set if
        # later version capabilities are set)
        V1_2: false
        # V1.1 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.1 (note, this need not be set if
        # later version capabilities are set).
        V1_1: false

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Application policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Admins"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    # Available types are "solo" and "kafka"
    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - orderer.org1.com:7050

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    Kafka:
        # Brokers: A list of Kafka brokers to which the orderer connects
        # NOTE: Use IP:port notation
        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Admins"
        # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

################################################################################
#
#   CHANNEL
#
#   This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for channel related parameters.
#
################################################################################
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Admins"

    # Capabilities describes the channel level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    TwoOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities


    SampleMultiNodeEtcdRaft:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            OrdererType: etcdraft
            EtcdRaft:
                Consenters:
                - Host: orderer.org1.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.com/orderers/orderer.org1.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.com/orderers/orderer.org1.com/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer2.org1.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.com/orderers/orderer2.org1.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.com/orderers/orderer2.org1.com/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer3.org1.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.com/orderers/orderer3.org1.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.com/orderers/orderer3.org1.com/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer4.org1.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.com/orderers/orderer4.org1.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.com/orderers/orderer4.org1.com/tls/server.crt
                - Host: orderer5.org1.com
                  Port: 7050
                  ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.com/orderers/orderer5.org1.com/tls/server.crt
                  ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/org1.com/orderers/orderer5.org1.com/tls/server.crt
            Addresses:
                - orderer.org1.com:7050
                - orderer2.org1.com:7050
                - orderer3.org1.com:7050
                - orderer4.org1.com:7050
                - orderer5.org1.com:7050

            Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
            - <<: *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue, the issue was because there was a version mismatch in fabric images.

Comment: which version image you use now ?

Comment: Hello GPC,
Can you give us more details on how you found out the version were not matching please?

Answer (score 1):

Versions of fabric that you defined in Capabilities Section doesn't compare with versions of your fabric docker images.